# Can grpc communicate with mac address insted of ip

Tags: dart, server, grpc

Currently my program use the IP of the other device in order to communicate over grpc.

Unfortunately the IP is changing all the time and I cannot continue the connection between the devices without updating it manually.

The connection between the devices is only on LAN and should blocked access from WAN.

Locking the IP of the device in the rowter settings is not an option this time.

Does grpc have a way to communicate over LAN (inside my network) using identification number or mac address that does not change over time?.

Related questions I found:

[grpc: Identify clients from same IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814457/grpc-identify-clients-from-same-ip-address)

[Reason for both a MAC and an IP address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/reason-for-both-a-mac-and-an-ip-address/3342#3342?newreg=66f4aa59fb4e45be8729cbf59e1ccbd8)

Answer (score 0):

In order to locate a machine based on its MAC address, you are talking about implementing ARP. This is something that is [not supported in dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33764) nor am I sure it would be advisable to go this route anyway. If setting a DHCP reservation on your router is not an option, are you able to skip DHCP and set a static IP on the receiving machine?

You could look into dynamic DNS which your router may support, or you may need to set up separately, but that will also require a static IP (for your DDNS server). If your machines can connect to the internet there are many DDNS services you can sign up for, but it sounds like that is not the case.